# Meaning of “the parties are directed to discuss in respect of any order or direction applied for, the purpose of the hearing...”

Tags: meaning

Context is Children's Act 1989.
The full sentence is this, I especially have a hard time understanding the bold part:

> The local authority having indicated it wishes to apply for an urgent interim care order, and this is to be dealt with at a separate hearing to the case management hearing, **the parties are directed to discuss in respect of any order or direction applied for, the purpose of the hearing, any directions that will be applied for, whether any part of the hearing will be contested and the length of the hearing, and the local authority shall inform the court in writing by 1.5.19."**

Answer (score 2):

> ..., the purpose of the hearing, any directions that
> will be applied for, whether any part of the hearing will be contested
> and the length of the hearing, and the local authority shall inform
> the court in writing by 1.5.19."

---

> In respect of any order or direction applied for, the parties are
> directed to discuss:
>
> (a) the purpose of the hearing,
>
> (b) any directions applied for
>
> (c) whether any part of the hearing will be contested
>
> (d) the length of the hearing
>
> and the local authority shall inform the court (about the results of the discussion) in writing by
> 1.5.19.